# What geronimo-web.xml does in WebSphere?

Tags: java, websphere, geronimo, websphere-ce

Recently I deployed a web app in WebSphere Community Edition v3. Eclipse smartly created `geronimo-web.xml` and `web.xml`. In JSF 2.0 we learned about the use of `web.xml` but what is the use of `geronimo-web.xml`? Can I ignore this file and simply remove from the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a server-specific deployment configuration file which allows you to configure server-specific properties from inside the deployed web application, such as class loading, character encoding, JNDI resources, etcetera.

Other servers have also this kind of server-specific configuration files. Glassfish has `glassfish-web.xml`, Tomcat has `context.xml`, etc. [IBM Websphere CE](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/community/) uses [Apache Geronimo](http://geronimo.apache.org/) as container.

You can just remove it if you want, but why would you?

#### See also:

- [Apache Geronimo `geronimo-web.xml` documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/geronimo-webxml.html)

---

Please note that the `web.xml` is not specific to JSF API, but to the Servlet API. JSF has the `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: Okkkk.... actually right now i am not using geronimo-web.xml. It was automatically build by Eclipse. but by removing this file, nothing is appearing in the browser.